# Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, typeerror

I'm relatively new to TypeScript. Know the basics but encountered a typecast error that I haven't found a solution to.

```
const [full, id]: string | null = /.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri)
```

typescript throws error on: [full, id]

```
Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
Type 'RegExpExecArray' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Type 'string | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

typecast Any ofc works but wanna do this properly, but haven't found what exactly TS wants me to do, while trying to search for an answer... So turn here now in hope for guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: You are destructuring Array type but telling compiler that this is `string`, not array. 
Use `RegExpExecArray | null` or generally speaking [string, string]. Anyway it's not correct assignement because return value legally can be `null` and you will get runtime error trying to destructurize `null`.

Comment: Yeah this possible null, is really throwing a wrench in my cogwheel...

const id: string | null = **/.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri)[1]**
Tried this but the whole regex part got error, TS casts as possibly null and cant type guard that?

Comment: You are constantly telling to compiler that `.exec` returns `string` but it's wrong. `.exec` return type is RegExpExecArray that has nothing common with string (but implements Array) or null. Just remove type from variable definition and leave `const id = ...`, compiler will assert correct type from `exec` function definition.

Comment: Yeah, seems it implicitly inferred type like you said. Buuut even after following your advice, it still throws **Object is possibly 'null'** on the whole regex part...
**const id = /.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri)[1]** Current variable form

Comment: What object is null? What is `item`? You have provided not enough information to reproduce the error. Of course `exec(...)` can be `null` but it's not a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution to the issue:

```
const id: RegExpExecArray | null = /.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri)
return id?.[1]?.replace(/:/g, '_')
```

This code properly type cast but also do the  check "object is possible 'null'" TS error message.

Thanks for everyones input. Learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the type that TypeScript suggests:

```js
const a: RegExpExecArray | null = /.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri)

console.log(a)
```

Comment: I did now but still get:
Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: Here's the typescript playground, it must be your TypeScript version. Playground is using 4.8.2:
shorturl.at/jku39

Comment: Remember you can't unpack a tuple from `.exec` -> `const result: RegExpExecArray | null`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another type-safe, and very simple solution:

`const [full, id] = /.*media\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/.exec(item.uri) || []`

and then you could:

```
  if(id){
   ...
  }
```